# Most efficient way to check three objects for not being null OR only two of them can be null

Tags: c#, validation, if-statement, comparison

I am struggling with a problem of validating three objects (A, B, C)

These are my conditions

- none of then can be null
- at most one of then can be not null

I want to resolve it without many if expression and creating monstrous code.

So

```
  A  B  C
A 1  0  0
B 0  1  0
C 0  0  1
```

as it show I need to achieve something like this pseudo table before only one of them can be true and all the other are false

Final

what expression can provide such validation?

Comment: I am confused by your conditions. There are 3 objects and you say "none of them can be null" so all 3 non null, then you say only 1 of 3 can be non null at a time. Those two conditions contradict. I must be misunderstanding.

Comment: Can you clarify something - do you mean `0` or `null`?

Comment: ok (i try to figura it for a while now so i am litte confused too) so i try simplest way to say it:   none of them can be null and maximally one of them can have value

Comment: Are these objects representing numbers? Do `1` and `0` in your grid above mean `non-null` and `null` or the numbers `one` and `zero`?

Comment: As I understand it: lolek is asking to check 3 _objects_ against `null`. If all 3 are `null`, _or_ only _one_ is `null` (and the other two non-null), do they consider a passing case. In other words, 2 or 3 items must be `null` to pass; if 1 or 0 items are `null`, it fails. The matrix lolek setup represents `1` being a pass, and `0` being a fail. (EDIT: But I agree, the matrix, I don't think is really correct. Weird having A,B,C on both axes)

Comment: thanks @ChrisSinclair for answer what i asking is: If all 3 are null - return false, if 2 are null - true, if 1 is null - false  but your answer leads to problem solution so i will follow and share result

Comment: @lolek: np. I fixed my answer according to your update. Sorry for misunderstanding. If it works, please remember to mark as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a helper method to do it (with tests), then at that point, have the code as messy or as clean as you wish in order to achieve your targets.

This is a fairly simple implementation; guarantees exactly 3 checks every time.

```
public static bool OnlyOneNotNull(object object1, object object2, object object3)
{
    if (object1 != null)
        return object2 == null && object3 == null;

    if (object2 != null)
        return object3 == null;

    return object3 != null;
}
```

Usage is simply:

```
if (OnlyOneNotNull(A, B, C))
{
    //do something
}
```